# How can I stop sending a preflight request on a redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors, csrf-protection

I discovered that six years ago, the previous developer commented out this line of code (Ruby, Rails):

`#protect_from_forgery`

I replaced it with the default:

`protect_from_forgery with: :exception`

and now I mysteriously get the following error when I try to add items to my cart while logged out:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://id.foo-staging.com/openid/checklogin?return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost.foo-staging.com%3A3000%2Fcart%2Fitems' (redirected from 'http://localhost.foo-staging.com:3000/cart/items') from origin 'http://localhost.foo-staging.com:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.`

I've pinned down that this is happening because of the following lines:

```
def get_user_identity_from_open_id_server
  redirect_to "#{OPEN_ID_PROVIDER_URL}/openid/checklogin?return_to=#{Rack::Utils.escape(request.url)}"
end

def open_id_authentication
  #stuff
  get_user_identity_from_open_id_server
end

before_filter :open_id_authentication
```

I understand what causes a preflight request, at a very high level, thanks to the documentation. But I don't think I'm doing any of those things.

```
* the request method is anything other than GET, HEAD, or POST
* you’ve set custom request headers other than Accept, Accept-Language, Content-Language, Content-Type, DPR, Downlink, Save-Data, Viewport-Width, or Width
* the Content-Type request header has a value other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain
```

So my initial question is how do I determine what is triggering the preflight request, and then maybe I can figure out how to prevent it from happening. Is this a situation that I can change on my end, or does something need to change on id.foo-staging.com (which I don't have access to, but could probably ask the right person to fix it for me).

I've been Googling all day, and nothing seems to make any sense to me, especially because I can't pin down precisely what's wrong.

I can solve the issue with this code:

`skip_before_filter :open_id_authentication, :only => [:create], :if => :current_user and :anonymous_cart`

But I have to assume that this is unsafe, from a security standpoint?

ETA: This is what I see on the `Network` tab for this request:

General:

`Request URL: https://id.foo-staging.com/openid/checklogin?return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost.foo-staging.com%3A3000%2Fcart%2Fitems
 Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Request Headers:

`Provisional headers are shown
 Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
 Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
 Origin: http://localhost.foo-staging.com:3000
 Referer: http://localhost.foo-staging.com:3000/p/Product0/1?id=1&slug=Product0
 User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36`

Query String Parameters:

`return_to: http://localhost.foo-staging.com:3000/cart/items`

I presume the problem is the `x-requested-with` request header. But I don't know how to resolve this.

EATA:

`Many JavaScript frameworks such as JQuery will automatically send this header along with any AJAX requests. This header cannot be sent cross-domain:`

I guess my only option is to figure out how to rewrite this without AJAX?

Comment: To determine what is triggering the preflight request, use the Network pane in browser devtools to examine the OPTIONS request and look at the value of the Access-Control-Request-Headers request header.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the preflight request you have to remove x-requested-with header but the error that you have is because the response location in the preflight call is different from the Origin.
To fix the problem, update your code to use the new URL as reported by the redirect, thereby avoiding the redirect.

Comment: How can he use the redirect url if browsers don't allow to use the response?